# Question regarding chain silicates

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In my textbook, $\ce{Li2SiO3}$ has been given as an example of single chain silicate. It is represented by general formula $\ce{(SiO3)^{2-}_n}$. In $\ce{Li2SiO3}$, since there is only one $\ce{SiO3^2-}$ ion, it means n=1 and therefore only one unit of $\ce{SiO3^2-}$ which combines with two lithium ions. But if there is only one silicate unit the number of oxygens should be four and the charge should be -4 and basically be a single isolated tetrahedron as $\ce{SiO3^2-}$ on its own will not be stable because Silicon needs 4 bonds.

Please clarify my doubt. Here is my textbook for reference.[image]

Comment: I am not quite getting your question. Are you asking why lithium silicate is formulated as $\ce{Li2SiO3}$ (n=1) although it is a chain silicate?

Comment: yes that's my question

Comment: See Wikipedia: "Silicate anions are often large polymeric molecules with an extense variety of structures, including chains and rings (as in polymeric metasilicate $\ce{[SiO3^{2-}]_n}$), double chains (as in $\ce{[Si2O5^{2-}]_n}$, and sheets (as in $\ce{[Si2O5^{2-}]_n}$." See the anion is a polymeric complex, they are formulated in simplified way as compounds with n=1 to avoid confusion (although they are classified as what type of silicate it contains).

Answer (score 2):

It is true that each tetrahedron has four oxygen atoms. But adding up the separate tetrahedra double-counts some oxygen atoms that are shared between two of them.

If two vehicles approach an all-way stop from different roads at the same time, laws (which may vary by state and by the type of vehicles) specify which one has the right-of way. Similarly, we can make a "law" saying, for instance, that when two of the tetrahedra in a chain from left to right have a bond to one oxygen atom the tetrahedron on the right effectively has the right to it for the purpose of single-counting.

Thus each tetrahedron gets only one of the shared oxygen atoms in this count along with the two terminal oxygens, therefore $\ce{SiO3}$ instead of $\ce{SiO4}$ (we do get the latter in compounds where the tetrahedra are completely apart, such as [$\ce{Mg2SiO4}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsterite)). Likewise the oxygen we counted with the neighboring tetrahedron effectively takes the electron pair polarized towards it, so the $\ce{SiO3}$ unit we identified in the chain is left with two negative charges rather than four.

The lithium ions are more straightforward. No such ion is bonded to a shared oxygen, so each one is associated with only one of the tetrahedra. It is thereby easy to see that there are two lithium ions to go with each $\ce{SiO3}$ unit, thus the overall empirical formula $\ce{Li2SiO3}$ (per tetrahedron).

Comment: my question is why are we not representing other combined tetrahedra in the formula Li2SiO3 why take only one combined tetrahedra in the formula?SINCE ITS IS COMBINED IN A CHAIN WHY NOT Li2(SiO3)2 or Li2(SiO3)3 ETC?

Comment: @AJknight There's *absolutely no need* for you to capitalise your text like that. Don't do that again on SE.

Comment: @AJknight because chain silicates are not made of specific discrete *molecules* with known numbers of tetrahedra. They are long chains and the formula represents their *average* composition.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the figure: for the chain silicate (inosilicate) the structural unit is constituted of two neighbouring tetrahedra. That is, you have 2 Si atoms + 7 O atoms. Anyway, only 5 atoms are fully contained in the structural unit, whereas 2 O atoms are linked with neighbouring structural units. Hence these 2 O atoms are half-contained in each structural unit and so they totally corresponds to 1 O atom. So the structural unit is consituted of 2 Si+ 6 O, corresponding to [SiO3]2-.

Comment: my question is why are we not representing other combined tetrahedra in the formula Li2SiO3 why take only one combined tetrahedra in the formula?SINCE ITS IS COMBINED IN A CHAIN WHY NOT Li2(SiO3)2 or Li2(SiO3)3 ETC?

Comment: @AJknight There's absolutely no need for you to capitalise your text like that. Don't do that again on SE. (Just like orthocresol says.)

Comment: @AJknight consider for example your proposed Li2(SiO3)2 formula: you have 2 Si+4 ions (giving +8 charges) and 6 O-2 (giving -12 charges). So you cannot balance the remaining -4 charges (8-12) with only 2 Li+ ions. So your simplified chemical formula corresponds to Li2SiO3.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to capitalise I might have pressed on accident.So even though there may be a chain of tetrahedra a compound will be formed only when the cation is able to neutralise the charge on anion which in this case is SiO3 2-?

Comment: Yes, since each tetrahedron is $\ce{SiO3^{2-}}$ when we properly count oxygen atoms, two $\ce{Li^+}$ ions will attach to each tetrahedron to neutralize it, which matches the unshared oxygen atoms where the net negative charges reside. Thus as I say, $\ce{Li2SiO3}$ is the formula per tetrahedron, thus also the overall atomic ratio.